# Swagger - API call with multiple paths

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I'm trying make a swagger file for an api GET request that has several paths to it. There's the GET /listings, GET /listings that passes in req.query.bidderId and another one that passes req.query.watcherId and one for req.query.winnerId. Currently swagger is saying

`Additional properties not allowed: /listings/{winnerId},/listings/{watcherId}`

I'm not really sure how to handle all the different scenarios for one API call in swagger file? 
Do I only need to have one with /{id}: and just let the express code do the rest? Is it that simple?

app.js

```
//GETS AUCTION LISTINGS

app.get("/api/listings", (req, res, next) => {
  query = {};
  if (req.query.bidderId && req.query.winner === "false") {

    query = { bidderId: req.query.bidderId };
    biddingGroupQuery = { biddingGroup: req.query.biddingGroup }

    Post.find({
      $and: [
        { biddingGroup: { $in: [req.query.bidderId] } },
        { auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } }
      ]
    })

      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Active Bids Listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
  } else if (req.query.bidderId && req.query.winner) {
    query = { bidderId: req.query.bidderId };
    biddingGroupQuery = { biddingGroup: req.query.biddingGroup };

    Post.find({
      $and: [
        { bidderId: req.query.bidderId },
        { auctionEndDateTime: { $lte: Date.now() } }
      ]
    })

      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
  } else if (req.query.watcherId) {
    Post.find({
      $and: [
        { watchingGroup: { $in: [req.query.watcherId] } },
        { auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } }
      ]
    })
      .populate("creator", "username")
      .then(documents => {
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "User's watchlist items retrieved!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
  } else if (!req.query.bidderId) {

    Post.find({ auctionEndDateTime: { $gte: Date.now() } })
      .populate("creator", "username")
      //.populate('watchlist', 'watchItemUniqueKey')
      .then(documents => {
        req.params.Id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.Id);
        res.status(200).json({
          message: "Auction listings retrieved successfully!",
          posts: documents
        });
      });
  }
});
```

swagger file

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Hello World App during dev, should point to your local machine
basePath: /v1
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
paths:
  /listings:
    x-swagger-router-controller: listings
    get:
      description: Return all the auction listings
      operationId: getAuctions
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success got all the listings
          schema:
            $ref: "/definitions/Listing"
        "500":
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string

  /listings/{id}:
    x-swagger-router-controller: listings
    get:
      description: My Bids, My Wins, and My Watchlist GET request
      operationId: getId
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          required: true
          type: string
          minimum: 5
          description: BidderId, WatcherId, or WinnerId
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success got all the listings
          schema:
            $ref: "/definitions/Listing"
        "500":
          description: Unexpected Error
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              message:
                type: string

definitions:
  Listing:
    properties:
      id:
        type: integer
      glassTitle:
        type: boolean
      startingBid:
        type: string
      increments:
        type: string
      shippingCost:
        type: string
      auctionType:
        type: string
      buyItNow:
        type: string
      snipingRules:
        type: string
      creator:
        type: string
      username:
        type: string
      biddingGroup:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      watchingGroup:
        type: array
        items:
          type: string
      lastBidderName:
        type: string
      currentBid:
        type: string
```

Comment: How is Swagger supposed to know whether the 1234 in `/listings/1234` is a `bidderId`, a `watcherId`, or a `winnerId`? The answer is, it can't. You need to pick one name for the property that comes after `/listings/` (e.g. `id`) and work with that. What you're doing is similar to trying to define the following three functions in JS: `const listings = bidderId => doStuff`, `const listings = watcherId => doStuff`, `const listings = winnerId => doStuff`. It won't work in Swagger for the same reason it won't work in JS.

Comment: I just updated my code above. If I understand you correctly, this would be the correct way and just let express handle the different paths right?

Comment: I don't think your code will work now. How does the code know whether 1234 in `listings/1234` is a `bidderId`, a `watcherId`, or a `winnerId`? Seems to be the same issue in a different place. You might want to try something like `/listings/by-bidder/{id}`, `/listings/by-watcher/{id}` and `/listings/by-winner/{id}` Or else just look for `id` in the code and figure out which kind of id it is (although this may not be possible).

Comment: Then I have no idea. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Generally, given a path like `/listings/{id}` in a well-designed REST application, I would expect the id to be a listing id, and not a bidder, watcher or winner id. I don't know express well enough, but you might also be able to do something like `/listings/bidder-{id}`, `/listings/watcher-{id}`, `/listings/winner-{id}`, but those don't look like proper REST paths to me.

Comment: bidderId, winnerId, and watcherId are just query parameters being passed to the backend in order to complete the mongoose queries. I'm handling the conditions of each call. I can't separate them into 3 separate app.get() requests. I just don't know how to integrate this logic into swagger

Comment: In that case, your Swagger definition is incorrect. You're defining these as separate paths rather than one `/listings/` path with several optional query strings. That's an OK thing to do. You just need to fix your Swagger definition. https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ . We should move this to chat if you want to continue the discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204630/discussion-between-user6680-and-tex).

Comment: Your Swagger file is correct, except you need to change `$ref: "/definitions/Listing"` to `$ref: "#/definitions/Listing"` - note the `#` at the beginning of the value.